# 2 Round Secure Multiparty Computation with BGW

Tags: multiparty-computation

The BGW protocol gives us security aginst a dishonest minority of parties, with round complexity linear in the function's circuit depth.
Several works (like [ABT18](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/894.pdf) or [LLW20](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1431.pdf)) use the BGW protocol to get 2-round MPC by reducing the functions degree to 2.

However, I don't see how BGW gives us a 2-round protocol. You need one round to share the inputs, one round for the multiplications and one final round to reconstruct the result, resulting in a 3-round protocol. What am I missing here? How can the multiplication round be merged into the input sharing or the reconstruction round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've thought about it a while back and figured it out.
You have the input sharing round and the reconstruction round. Every round beyond that is used for *degree-reduction* of the secret sharing. Since the Shamir Secret Sharing in this context (honest majority) supports up to one non-interactive multiplication, you don't need to perform a degree reduction for the last multiplication.
For example, a degree 2 function is computed in two rounds:

1. An input sharing round.
2. Non-interactive multiplication of the shares to compute the degree-2 function.
3. A reconstruction round.

A degree-3 function would require an additional degree-reduction round after step 2 - totalling 3 rounds.